# Find the probability that the distance between $a$ and $b$ is greater than $3$.

Tags: probability

Two real numbers $a$ and $b$ are selected at random along the x-axis such that
$−2 \leq b \leq 0$ and $0 \leq a \leq 3$.

Can someone explain how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would have attempted it this way: let us first find the probability when there are finitely many choices for $b$. Say $b\in A\subset[-2,0]$ and that $|A|=n<\infty$.

The required probability is $1-P(a-b\le3)$.

The probability of chosing $b=x\in A$ is $1/n$.

The probability that $a\le b+3$ is$$P(a-b\le3|b=x)=\frac{l[0,x+3]}{l[0,3]}=\frac{x+3}3$$where $l[c,d]=d-c$ is the length of the interval $[c,d]$. Then you have,$$P(a-b\le3)=\sum_1^n P(a-b\le3|b=x_i)\times P(b=x_i)\\=\sum_1^n\frac{x_i+3}3\times\frac1n=\frac{3n+\sum_1^nx_i}{3n}=1+\frac{\sum_1^nx_i}{3n}$$The answer we require is just $$P(a-b\ge3)=1-\Big[1+\frac{\sum_1^nx_i}{3n}\Big]=-\frac{\sum_1^nx_i}{3n}$$So the solution to your original problem is the value of the limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{\sum_1^nx_i}{3n}$$To solve the limit, write $x_i$ as $-2+j/n$ with $j$ ranging from $0\to2n$. The limit then transforms to$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{\sum_1^{2n}-2+j/n}{3n}=\int_0^2\frac{2-x}3dx=4/3-2/3=2/3$$